# Issue with .loc and np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, nan, pandas-loc

I'm running into issues with the following bit of code:

```
student_data_df.loc[(student_data_df.school_name=="Thomas High School") & (student_data_df.grade=='9th'), student_data_df.reading_score] = np.nan
```

Basically I'm trying to use .loc on a dataframe to pull a specific school name and grade, then alter all of the scores in a column to NaN to invalidate them. However, I'm running into an issue where when I try to run the cell, nothing happens. No error, nothing prints.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Break your code into separate lines to make it understandable and debuggable:

```
school_matches = student_data_df.school_name=="Thomas High School"
grade_matches = student_data_df.grade=='9th'
rows = school_matches & grade_matches
column = student_data_df.reading_score

student_data_df.loc[rows, column] = np.nan
```

I think the first three lines are fine, the problem is in the fourth line.  You are "locating" in two dimensions:

1. Rows which contain both "Thomas High School" and "9th" grade.
2. Columns which contain...the reading score?  I bet this is not what you wanted.  I bet what you wanted was to select the reading_score column as the one to set to `nan`.  To do that, you need:

```
column = 'reading_score'
```

What we're doing now is locating the column called 'reading_score', instead of locating the scores' values (which is nonsensical).

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html